# Regarding iCarousel and labels iOS

Tags: ios, icarousel

I have 2 labels.

First label, named "label" is placed inside every view within the carousel. The string/text of the label is the view's index.

```
label.text = [[items1 objectAtIndex:index] stringValue];
```

I also have a second label (outside the carousel) named "outsideLabel". 
I want the outsideLabel's string/text to be the view's index aswell (always the view being in front of the carousel).

```
outsideLabel.text = [[items1 objectAtIndex:index] stringValue];
```

Somehow I am doing it wrong and wonder how I shall code this in order to show the proper number in outsideLabel's string/text (always the view being in front). The code somewhat shows the correct numbers but get messed up when scrolling backwards in the carousel. The carouseltype is timeMachine.

My current code:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{   
    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];

        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        if (carousel == carousel1)
        {

        CGRect test = CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20);
        self.label.frame = test;

         }
        else {
            CGRect test = CGRectMake(50, 40, 40, 40);
            self.label.frame = test;

            }
        [view addSubview:label];

    }
    else
    {
        label = [[view subviews] lastObject];
    }

    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
        //items in this array are numbers
        outsideLabel.text = [[items1 objectAtIndex:index] stringValue];

        label.text = [[items1 objectAtIndex:index] stringValue];

         ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:[view1background objectAtIndex:index]];

    }
    else
    {

       //not relevant....
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: have you tried delegate method of iCarousel - - (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(iCarousel *)carousel ? Try setting value here.. hope this might help u

Answer (score 2):

From the code you've provided, it looks like you're not initializing the `outsideLabel` in the right place. To be safe, you should initialize all your subviews inside the block where you are checking if the view is `nil`. Another safe convention is to assign tags to all your subviews, so that you can later retrieve them from views that are reused, as in the code below. For easy reference, and to avoid errors, I define constants for these tags at the top of my implementation file, like this:

```
#define INSIDE_LABEL_TAG  1
#define OUTSIDE_LABEL_TAG 2
```

This is much safer, since it doesn't depend on the structure of the views, as is the case with your code, where you get the last view:

```
label = [[view subviews] lastObject];
```

Try initializing `outsideLabel` inside that block, and use tags. The pattern used in initialization is identical to that used for the subviews of `UITableView` cells in a `UITableViewDataSource` delegate:

```
(UITableViewCell * _Nonnull)tableView:(UITableView * _Nonnull)tableView
                cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * _Nonnull)indexPath
```

Here is some pseudo code that shows where I would use tags and initialize the `outsideLabel`:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
    if (view == nil)
    {
        //Configure the view
        ...

        /*  Initialize views for all carousels  */

        //Initialize the insideLabel and set its tag
        ...
        insideLabel.tag = INSIDE_LABEL_TAG;

        //Initialize the outsideLabel and set its tag
        ...
        outsideLabel.tag = OUTSIDE_LABEL_TAG;

        if (carousel == carousel1)
        {
            //Do any carousel-specific configurations
        }

        //Add all subviews initialized in this block
        [view addSubview:label];
        [view addSubview:outsideLabel];
    }
    else
    {
        //Get the subviews from an existing view
        insideLabel = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:INSIDE_LABEL_TAG];
        outsideLabel = (UILabel *)[view viewWithTag:OUTSIDE_LABEL_TAG];
    }

    if (carousel == carousel1)
    {
        //Set the values for each subview
    } else {
       //Other carousels...
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want the "time machine" style carousel. I don't see your code setting the carousel type anywhere. Don't you need to set the carousel type?

Comment: I am setting the type in viewDidLoad method. And yes it is already timemachine. Still I only see 1 card instead of several cards.

Comment: Have you looked at the iCarousel demo apps? They include a working demo of the Time Machine look. (It's been a while since I've set up a new iCarousel, so I don't remember the details off the top of my head.)